# SSH tunnel <--> iptables NAT port forwarding - HOWTO?

Tags: iptables, portforwarding, nat, ssh-tunnel

I need to set up access to the HTTP(S) servers on devices like KVMs and PDUs on a private network (192.168.0.0/24). I must get through an isolated network (10.0.0.0/8) limited to ports 22 and 443.  I have a dual-NIC Linux server inside the network that serves as a gateway to the private network. See diagram Here:
[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlWM4.png)

I need to use a forward SSH tunnel to get to the Linux gateway, then use iptables NAT to route HTTP(s) traffic to the web frontends on the devices.

I've observed with both tcpdump and iptables trace that the inbound HTTP(s) request through the SSH tunnel shows up on interface lo , not eth1 as one might expect.

This has led me to come up with the following nat and filter rules:

```
*nat
-A PREROUTING -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.100:80
-A PREROUTING -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8081 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.101:443
-A POSTROUTING -d 10.0.0.0/8 -o lo -j SNAT --to-source <10.gateway_IP>
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [37234:5557621]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [26648:27864039]
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.0.0/24  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

So, when I set up the tunnel with:

```
ssh -L 8080:<gateway>:8080 <user>:@<gateway>
```

Then making sure on the gateway:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

and then execute `http://localhost:8080`,

The packets make it out of the tunnel onto the gateway, out of interface lo, but iptables doesn't seem to forward it to the destination in the PREROUTING rule. stderr from the tunnel returns "Connection refused."

What am I missing?